# does PHP's cURL object have a timeout option that automaticly stop the script?

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I have a small PHP script that run via corn job.
This script reads records from a database then using PHP's SimpleXMLElement object I create a .xml string. finally I make a cURL call to an API and I transfer the file over.

the problem that I am running into is that if the database query has lots more records that usual then the script does not seem to run thru all the records. It seems that the cURL execute a `break;` which will stop the foreach loop from going thru all the records.

the code is something like this

```
$results = array(........);
foreach($result AS $r){
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement();
 $UpFile =  $xml->addChild('UpFile');
...
...
...
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $xml->asXML())  );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result_xml = simplexml_load_string( $result);

        if (!$result){
            echo curl_error($ch) . '<br />';
            return false;
        }

        curl_close($ch);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a limit the the cURL object has that will auto break the foreach loop? if not any clue what could be causing this issue?

thank you

Comment: well.. you are returning false when a curl error occurs.

Comment: You have to replace `return false;` with `continue;`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't return false when you don't get $result.

Second, you can increase the timeout like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds - the default is 30, I believe
```

And also, on the top of the script

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just made the suggested changed. I will check it in the few day coming up and see if this is still an issue after the changes. thank you

Comment: This did not work. The set_time_limit(0); should now be a problem because the script executes with in 5 seconds. but the problem seems to be that the loop does not loop all the records. I am not sure what else I can check for? thank you for your help and time